# How about UI automation testing for iOS app with instruments & Javascripts

Tags: ios, automated-tests, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Get knowing the automation UI testing for iOS apps from WWDC2010 video session, but no practices for it.

From codeproject [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/UI_Automation_Testing.aspx),we can have one example.

Questions here to hear from people who have involved this.

Any limitations ? Any good practices ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend to start with [this blogpost](http://alexvollmer.com/posts/2010/07/03/working-with-uiautomation/) by Alex Wollmer. He made a very useful javascript library: [tuneup_js](https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js) with test() function that enables test separation and useful helpers and assertions for writing tests for Automation Instrument.