# Programmatically Simulate Keyboard Events on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, keypress

I was wondering if it would be possible to simulate keyboard events - like key down and key up characters - and send them to the iOS device. Basically, I want to simulate a user pressing a key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at "Automated GUI testing for iOS", for example [Automated testing for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402389/automated-testing-for-iphone) and [How about UI automation testing for iOS app with instruments & Javascripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798485/how-about-ui-automation-testing-for-ios-app-with-instruments-javascripts)

You might not want a full blown automated test solution, but that way you can simulate your keyboard events.

There is also a blogpost mentioned: http://alexvollmer.com/posts/2010/07/03/working-with-uiautomation/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. But you could write code in textfield delegate or use NSNotificationCenter to get notification of each keypress. If that's what you are looking for.