# How simulate keypress using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, keypress

How simulate pressing the keyboard button?

**I tried:**

```
let src = CGEventSource(stateID: CGEventSourceStateID.hidSystemState)

let cmdd = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x38, keyDown: true)
let cmdu = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x38, keyDown: false)
let spcd = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x31, keyDown: true)
let spcu = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x31, keyDown: false)

spcd?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand;

let loc = CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap

cmdd?.post(tap: loc)
spcd?.post(tap: loc)
spcu?.post(tap: loc)
cmdu?.post(tap: loc)
```

**And:**

```
let controlKeyDownEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: CGKeyCode(kVK_Control), keyDown: true)
   controlKeyDownEvent?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand
   controlKeyDownEvent?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
```

**But I got errors:**

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'CGEvent' 
Use of unresolved identifier 'CGKeyCode' 
Use of unresolved identifier 'kVK_Control'
```

and etc.

How do I use this code?

What kind of framework to connect?

Or how can I do it differently?

Comment: which OS are you aiming for here: macOS or iOS ?

Comment: Did you import CoreGraphics? Is this for macOS?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, rmaddy iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CGEventSourceRef only exists on macOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventsource).

You might have other options to try out.  [Check out Olaf's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339004/programmatically-simulate-keyboard-events-on-the-iphone).

Otherwise you'll need to take a step back and figure out how *else* to test the code behind your UI without involving the keyboard.